# Pydantic: Disable root_validator in child class

Tags: python, pydantic

Is it possible to disable or remove or replace superclass's root validator in `pydantic` for child classes?

Here is an example:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, root_validator


def parent_validator(cls, values):
    print('parent validator triggered')
    return values


def child_validator(cls, values):
    print('child validator triggered')
    return values


class ParentModel(BaseModel):
    name: str
    _custom_validator = root_validator()(parent_validator)


class ChildModel(ParentModel):
    _custom_validator = root_validator()(child_validator)


m1 = ParentModel(name='example name')
# outputs:
# parent validator triggered

m2 = ChildModel(name='example name 2')
# outputs:
# parent validator triggered
# child validator triggered
```

Expected behaviour:

```
m2 = ChildModel(name='example name 2')
# outputs:
# child validator triggered
```

A perfect solution for me would be something like this:

```
class ChildModel(ParentModel):
    _custom_validator = None
```

but it doesn't seem to work.
Tried with `pydantic==1.9.1`

Comment: This sounds unusual. Have you considered changing the inheritance? If two classes have different validations, maybe it does not make sense that one of them inherits from the other. If those two classes have common fields or methods they could inherit from a third class that does not have the problematic validation.

Comment: @HernánAlarcón yes, that's what I did for now. Just was wondering if this kind of overriding should work.